# Can I improve this code for better performance?

Tags: java, rest, jdbc

I have a REST WS in JAVA using jersey that connects to database. I don't know what should be the ideal time for execution but I feel the time it takes is too much.

The actual call to DB completes in range of 0-3 milliseconds but the overall time to complete the REST request takes >9 milliseconds.

Below is one of the method:

```
connection // declared as instance variable
preparedStatement //declared as instance variable 
public int insertSubscription(ActiveWatchers activeWatchers) throws SQLException {

        int index = 0;

        try {
            connection = DAOConnectionFactory.getConnection();
            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(INSERT_SUBS);
            preparedStatement.setObject(++index, activeWatchers.getPresentityURI());
            preparedStatement.setObject(++index, activeWatchers.getCallId());
            preparedStatement.setObject(++index, activeWatchers.getToTag());
            preparedStatement.setObject(++index, activeWatchers.getFromTag());
            preparedStatement.setObject(++index, activeWatchers.getToUser());
            preparedStatement.setObject(++index, activeWatchers.getToDomain());
            preparedStatement.setObject(++index, activeWatchers.getWatcherUsername());
            preparedStatement.setObject(++index, activeWatchers.getWatcherDomain());
            preparedStatement.setObject(++index, activeWatchers.getEvent());
            preparedStatement.setObject(++index, activeWatchers.getEventId());
            preparedStatement.setObject(++index, activeWatchers.getLocalCseq());
            preparedStatement.setObject(++index, activeWatchers.getRemoteCseq());
            preparedStatement.setObject(++index, activeWatchers.getExpires());
            preparedStatement.setObject(++index, activeWatchers.getStatus());
            preparedStatement.setObject(++index, activeWatchers.getReason());
            preparedStatement.setObject(++index, activeWatchers.getRecordRoute());
            preparedStatement.setObject(++index, activeWatchers.getContact());
            preparedStatement.setObject(++index, activeWatchers.getLocalContact());
            preparedStatement.setObject(++index, activeWatchers.getVersion());
            preparedStatement.setObject(++index, activeWatchers.getSocketInfo());

            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            int status = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            logger.debug("insertSubscription elasped time {}", (end - start));
            logger.debug("Insert returned with status {}.", status);
            return status;

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            logger.error("Error while adding new subscription by {}@{} for {} into database.", activeWatchers.getWatcherUsername(), activeWatchers.getWatcherDomain(), activeWatchers.getPresentityURI(), ex);
            throw ex;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("Error while adding new subscription by {}@{} for {} into database.", activeWatchers.getWatcherUsername(), activeWatchers.getWatcherDomain(), activeWatchers.getPresentityURI(), ex);
            throw ex;
        } finally {
            DAOConnectionFactory.closeConnection(connection, preparedStatement, null);
        }

    }
```

**The REST part**

```
subscriptionDAO //declared as instance variable
@POST
    @Consumes("application/json")
    public Response addSubscription(ActiveWatchers activeWatchers) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        logger.debug("addSubscription start time {}", start);
        subscriptionDAO = new SubscriptionDAO();
        try {
            subscriptionDAO.insertSubscription(activeWatchers);
            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            logger.debug("addSubscription elasped time {}", (end - start));
            return Response.status(201).build();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("Error while creating subscription.", ex);
            return Response.status(500).entity("Server Error").build();
        }
    }
```

I have a lot of other similar functions for different operations and each has similar behavior which is affecting the overall performance of the system.

Thanks

Comment: Unrelated, but: `executeUpdate()` does not return a "status". It returns the number of rows that were affected by the statement.

Comment: why would you make connection and preparedStatement instance variables??

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you are correct. I am using the count as  status.

Comment: @NathanHughes Shall I make them class variables? I do not have much coding experience so unaware of all the best practices.

Comment: The granularity of System.currentTimeMillis() depends on the underlying operating system, and is not very accurate (may be incremented in steps of some milliseconds). Therefore it's not suitable for measuring elapsed time in the range of milliseconds, and deltas of System.nanoTime() should be used instead.

Comment: @PeterWalser I am sure you are right and I will try with nanoTime as well but I always see this behavior, maybe millis are +/- by 1 but the point is whatever the code is before/after the DB call takes a lot of time.

Comment: The granularity on some platforms can be quite coarse, in the range of 15-16 ms, which among other issues was a mayor cause of animation timing problems prior to the introduction of nano time in Java 1.5.

Comment: Making them class variables is going the wrong direction, getting even broader. When you make these variables' scope anything but local, you risk having multiple threads access them concurrently. You should have a connection pool (which is threadsafe), and retrieve connections from it for your queries, referencing the connection from a local variable.

Comment: @NathanHughes Thanks. Initially, they were created as local but some experienced programmer asked me to make them global so that I don't recreate the reference each time.

Comment: That's *terrible* advice. you use a different object every time. Whether you initialize a new variable is inconsequential. and you will create severe concurrency bugs this way.

Comment: @NathanHughes exact same point I made to him but he said you should learn about references and how they are used. I bowed to his experience :).

Comment: @NathanHughes would you mind doing a quick code review? It's just 10 small classes out of which half are similar.

Comment: See the [help center](http://www.codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) over at [codereview.se]; if your code works as intended that's where you should post your code for a "quick code review" ;-)

Answer (score 1):

> The actual call to DB completes in range of 0-3 milliseconds but the overall time to complete the REST request takes >9 milliseconds.

I think if your web layer causes only 6ms overhead, then it is pretty fast. I guess that 6ms is spent mostly with reflection-heavy JSON deserialization (into an ActiveWatcher instance).

First, you should profile your app with VisualVM (a GUI app, part of the JDK), because doing optimization based on guessing is just a lame thing.

If it turns out to be the json deserialization being the bottleneck, then you may develop a custom jackson deserializer for your ActiveWatchers class, where you can take the advantage of hand-written code over slow reflection-based behavior.

But I still think that your 9ms is fast enough.

Comment: Ok, I'll profile the code. If you say that 9 ms is fast enough I may agree but I have a C code which calls this WS and does lot more than this finishes within couple of ms that's why I feel this is too high.